# Numpy: recode numeric array to which quintile each element belongs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, percentile

I have a numeric vector `a`:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(100)
```

I wish to get the vector (*or any other vector*) recoded so that each element is either 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, according to which `a` quintile it is in (could be more general for any quantile, like quartile, decile etc.).

This is what I'm doing. There has to be something more elegant, no?

```py
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore

n_quantiles = 5

def get_quantile(i, a, n_quantiles):
    if a[i] >= max(a):
        return n_quantiles - 1
    return int(percentileofscore(a, a[i])/(100/n_quantiles))

a_recoded = np.array([get_quantile(i, a, n_quantiles) for i in range(len(a))])

print(a)
print(a_recoded)
```

> ```
> [0.04708996 0.86267278 0.23873192 0.02967989 0.42828385 0.58003015
>  0.8996666  0.15359369 0.83094778 0.44272398 0.60211289 0.90286434
>  0.40681163 0.91338397 0.3273745  0.00347029 0.37471307 0.72735901
>  0.93974808 0.55937197 0.39297097 0.91470761 0.76796271 0.50404401
>  0.1817242  0.78244809 0.9548256  0.78097562 0.90934337 0.89914752
>  0.82899983 0.44116683 0.50885813 0.2691431  0.11676798 0.84971927
>  0.38505195 0.7411976  0.51377242 0.50243197 0.89677377 0.69741088
>  0.47880953 0.71116534 0.01717348 0.77641096 0.88127268 0.17925502
>  0.53053573 0.16935597 0.65521692 0.19042794 0.21981197 0.01377195
>  0.61553814 0.8544525  0.53521604 0.88391848 0.36010949 0.35964882
>  0.29721931 0.71257335 0.26350287 0.22821314 0.8951419  0.38416004
>  0.19277649 0.67774468 0.27084229 0.46862229 0.3107887  0.28511048
>  0.32682302 0.14682896 0.10794566 0.58668243 0.16394183 0.88296862
>  0.55442047 0.25508233 0.86670299 0.90549872 0.04897676 0.33042884
>  0.4348465  0.62636481 0.48201213 0.49895892 0.36444648 0.01410316
>  0.46770595 0.09498391 0.96793139 0.03931124 0.64286295 0.50934846
>  0.59088907 0.56368594 0.7820928  0.77172038]
>
> [0 4 1 0 2 3 4 0 4 2 3 4 2 4 1 0 1 3 4 2 1 4 3 2 0 3 4 3 4 4 4 2 2 1 0 4 1 
> 3 2 2 4 3 2 3 0 3 4 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 3 4 2 4 1 1 1 3 1 1 4 1 0 3 1 2 1 1 1 0 
> 0 3 0 4 2 1 4 4 0 1 2 3 2 2 1 0 2 0 4 0 3 2 3 2 3 3]
> ```

Update: just wanted to say this is so easy in R:
[How to get the x which belongs to a quintile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958324/how-to-get-the-x-which-belongs-to-a-quintile)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing entries in a numpy array with their quantile index with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769979/replacing-entries-in-a-numpy-array-with-their-quantile-index-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `argpartition`. Example:

```
>>> a = np.random.random(20)
>>> N = len(a)
>>> nq = 5
>>> o = a.argpartition(np.arange(1, nq) * N // nq)
>>> out = np.empty(N, int)
>>> out[o] = np.arange(N) * nq // N
>>> a
array([0.61238649, 0.37168998, 0.4624829 , 0.28554766, 0.00098016,
       0.41979328, 0.62275886, 0.4254548 , 0.20380679, 0.762435  ,
       0.54054873, 0.68419986, 0.3424479 , 0.54971072, 0.06929464,
       0.51059431, 0.68448674, 0.97009023, 0.16780152, 0.17887862])
>>> out
array([3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0])
```

Comment: You both are getting different answers. Isn't it?

Comment: No @KaranShah, checked it, same answers.

Comment: Accepting this as I have nothing better. But it's amazing to me numpy doesn't supply you with a basic tool to do this recoding by ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using [pd.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100))
df.columns = ['values']
# Apply the quantiles
gdf = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.loc[:, 'values'], np.arange(0, 1.2, 0.2)))['values'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).to_frame()
# Make use of the automatic indexing to assign quantile numbers
gdf.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
# Re-expand the grouped list of values. Method provided by @Zero at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows
gdf['values'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('values').reset_index()
```